# Lock Firefox Settings and Changes / Addons and about:

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, blocking, lock, firefox-profile

I would like to lock my Firefox.

The quest is: don't let anyone or anything change something on my Firefox. I would like to block any changes (add-ons, settings, prefs).

I created:

- `as.js` with:

  ```
  pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
  pref("general.config.filename", "mozilla.cfg");
  ```
- `Mozilla.cfg` with:

  ```
  //
  lockpref("browser.startup.homepage", about:home);
  ```

It worked but only for startup page ...

I can change/install add-on and I can change everything on `about:config`.

Btw `Lockpref"xxxxxxx"` is very long and difficult because there are a lot of names and find the right names is so boring.